# how or where to set parameters for vm arguments in eclipse using phonegap and mgwt

Tags: eclipse, gwt, cordova, virtual-machine, mgwt

iam using mgwt and phonegap for my mobile web project and iam working with eclipse.
to use phonegap in my project i need to set two parameters to vm arguments which are described below on this side.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/FileModule

these are the two parameters.
-DinsecurePhoneGapFileApi=true

-DphonegapFilePath="path to the directory you want to use"

i really dont know where or how to add these paramaters.

please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your runtime configuration in eclipse under the arguments tab you can pass parameters to your jvm, see:

[image: screen shot eclipse]